# Differentiate the following function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$y = \sqrt {\sin x} = (\sin x)^{\frac 12}$$

\begin{aligned}
{dy \over dx} & = \frac 12 (\sin x)^{-\frac {1}2}{d\over dx} \sin x 
\\ & = \frac 12 (\sin x)^{-\frac 12} \cos x 
\\ & = \frac{\cos x}{ 2\sqrt{\sin x}}
\end{aligned}

Is this correct?

Please excuse the poor layout, i'm new :'(

Comment: Please use $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for the derivative...

Comment: See my answer below, and by the way, welcome aboard! :)

Answer (score 9):

Yes my friend, you are correct!

For future derivative checks, try [www.wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning Wolfram Alpha, very handy sometimes ^^

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{\sin x} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\sin x}} \frac{d}{dx}\sin x =  \frac{\cos x}{2 \sqrt{\sin x}} $$
by the chain rule.

Comment: I think that's exactly what the OP found, in his post. No need to redo work done correctly.

Answer (score 2):

1) If $y = \sin(x)^{1/2}$ then $y \neq \dfrac{1}{2}\sin(x)^{-1/2}\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin(x)$ (a function and its derivative are two different things)

2) If $y = \dfrac{1}{2}\sin(x)^{-1/2}\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin(x)$ then $y \neq \dfrac{1}{2}\sin(x)^{1/2}\cos(x)$ (minus sign is missing)

You result is correct but your redaction is wrong.